# Delete toolbar actionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I'm having some troubles with toolbar actionBar in fragments. I know I can hide it using

```
ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

But I want to remove it completely, because if I use the above code, it leave a blank space. (Id' post an image to show you the result but I can't because I have no reputation yet)

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you add Toolbar to layout?

Comment: Because depending in the fragment I am, I need a toolbar or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you setting

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

`Toolbar` is like any other view in android so you can hide toolbar

```
toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

use Style

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually this solution do the same as `actionBar.hide()`: it delete the toolbar but it still leave a blank space.